# Initializing a pointer but not getting the same value zero

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, delete-operator

My question comes as a result of compiling the code below in two separate compilers. I entered the following line of code in Eclipse Helios and Online GDB Compiler and got different results:

```
    int* ptr1 = new int;  
    int* ptr2 = new int(20);  

    cout << "Value of ptr1 = " << *ptr1 << "\n"; 
    cout << "Value of ptr2 = " << *ptr2 << "\n"; 

    delete ptr1; // Destroying ptr1 
    delete ptr2; // Detroying ptr2
```

For **Online GDB** the result is:

```
Value of ptr1 = 0
Value of ptr2 = 20
```

However, **Eclipse Helios** the result is:

```
Value of ptr1 = 225472
Value of ptr2 = 20
```

Is it just telling me *ptr1* is now holding some garbage value in it rather than zero?

Comment: Reading an uninitialized variable is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it just telling me ptr1 is now holding some garbage value in it rather than zero?

Yes, the value isn't guaranteed to be zero. For [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization),

(emphasis mine)

> otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to **indeterminate values**.

So both the observed results from two compilers are reasonable.

Comment: I understand why both are acceptable. Is it just how the compilers are written or said to evaluate these types of situations?

Comment: @Euxitheos because it is not part of standard and compilers can do whatever they want.

Comment: @Euxitheos And even the compiler do something which are not required by the compiler, e.g. initializing the value to `0` for this case, you shouldn't depend on them; they're not guaranteed.